# Product Listing by SKU in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I would like my store products to be displayed in SKU (ascending) order by default when looking at the category product listing pages in magento 2. Can someone please tell me how to:

Make this the default sort option.

Add SKU as a user selectable option on the product listing pages.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2,  I hope this works because it is really easy and you don't have to touch any code:

1. In the admin panel, go to

> Store > Under Attributes > Product

2. Find the attribute code **sku**
3. In it, under StoreFront Properties, change the **"Use for Sorting in
   Product Listing"** to **"Yes"** and save
4. Go to **Stores > Configuration** and click on the Catalog section under
   catalog tab
5. Under StoreFront, change the **"Product Listing Sort by"** to **"SKU"** and
   save

You can also change the default product listing for each category in **Catalog > Categories** under the **Display Settings** tab of your selected category.

**I hope this will help**